# Lost section number ordering in Word 2010 after adding a plaintext list

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Suppose I have the following document structure [edit: chose a cooking recipe example]

```
8. Spaghetti alla Sorrentina (formatted as Title 1)

Here are the ingredients to make this fantastic pasta (text body)

1. Spaghetti
2. Tomato sauce
[...]
7. Provola cheese (still text body, all formatted as numbered list)

Cook pasta for half of time needed, add sauce, add provola, put in oven blah blah blah

9. Struffoli (formatted as Title 1)

Blah blah blah (formatted as text body)
```

My problem is that Word insists to number Section 9 (Struffoli) with `eight`, thus linking that section to the previous text-body list (ingredients list). However, I want section 9 (title 1) to be the next item of Spaghetti's list.

So it becomes

```
8. Spaghetti alla Sorrentina (formatted as Title 1)

Here are the ingredients to make this fantastic pasta (text body)

1. Spaghetti
2. Tomato sauce
[...]
7. Provola cheese (still text body, all formatted as numbered list)

Cook pasta for half of time needed, add sauce, add provola, put in oven blah blah blah

------>8. Struffoli (formatted as Title 1)
```

**I know** I can modify Section 9's list element by forcing the list to start from 9 by right-clicking on `8`, selecting submenu "Numbered lists" and then "Set enumeration value" (whatever they are called in English-Word), **but** if I change earlier elements, move the section, etc. I have to manually change all numbers.

Screenshot below shows Word menu when right-clicking on a list item (useless to make it larger because it overlaps the list itself)

[image]

### How to reproduce

Open an empty Word document and make it like this (except for final chapter)

[image]

Then select Title 1, type `4.` for paragraph number 4 and you get `5.` with thunder icon!!

### The question is

How to tell Word that `Struffoli`, formatted as `Title 1`, belongs to the numbered list of `Spaghetti alla Sorrentina` thus following its enumeration?

Comment: I assume you can't use real pictures? It's hard to know what you mean from the description

Comment: I assume you can't understand Italian, but anyway...

Comment: Somebody edited the post but that editing was lost because I was rewriting the example. Please fix again if needed

Comment: @DaveRook Correct, if I use Set Numbering Value what you describe happens. But most importantly the question is about telling Word that Struffoli is part of listing A (the chapter listing) instead of listing B (the spaghetti ingredient list) and it should follow that enumeration, which would solve any problem a priori and maintain the document better-structured

Comment: @DaveRook I format paragraph titles with Title 1. They appear in automatic summary. I highlighted the formatting in the text example because I can't play with font size when writing code-style text on superuser (superuser also play with lists if I put numbers at the beginning of a non-code-formatted line in the editor)

Comment: If I indent the bullets I get the list like "3.1, 3.2" in the third paragraph of the example document I just screenshotted

Comment: Thank you for doing the last picture. Where it currently shows 5, I assume you want it to be a 4?

Comment: @DaveRook precisely I want 4 and when I mouse-over 4 to highlight the corresponding 3, 2, 1 of paragraph titles. Formatting is only for visual purposes when reading the text and for creating the autoindex

Comment: This issue is caused by using the Heading1 style (or any styles). If you were OK to manually format them, this issue would not exist. I assume you are using a table of contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution that works with title formatting:

With reference to the cooking recipes, once you have written section 8's body (Spaghetti)

```
8. Spaghetti alla Sorrentina (formatted as Title 1)

Here are the ingredients to make this fantastic pasta (text body)

1. Spaghetti
2. Tomato sauce
[...]
7. Provola cheese (still text body, all formatted as numbered list)

Cook pasta for half of time needed, add sauce, add provola, put in oven blah blah blah
```

Temporarily change the numbered list of ingredients to a bulleted list (use the blue-circled button in screenshot after selecting all the elements in the list)

[image: Home strip]

```
8. Spaghetti alla Sorrentina (formatted as Title 1)

Here are the ingredients to make this fantastic pasta (text body)

*. Spaghetti
*. Tomato sauce
[...]
*. Provola cheese (still text body, all formatted as numbered list)

Cook pasta for half of time needed, add sauce, add provola, put in oven blah blah blah
```

Then write Section 9's title with `Title 1` and numbered list formatting (set title 1, start typing `9.` and go on), you get correct number and that item is associated to chapter list as required, as shown by highlighting it

```
8. Spaghetti alla Sorrentina (formatted as Title 1)

Here are the ingredients to make this fantastic pasta (text body)

*. Spaghetti
*. Tomato sauce
[...]
*. Provola cheese (still text body, all formatted as numbered list)

Cook pasta for half of time needed, add sauce, add provola, put in oven blah blah blah

9. Struffoli
```

Now, finally, select all the bulleted items and convert them to a numbered list by using the red-circled command in the `Home` ribbon strip

```
8. Spaghetti alla Sorrentina (formatted as Title 1)

Here are the ingredients to make this fantastic pasta (text body)

1. Spaghetti
2. Tomato sauce
[...]
7. Provola cheese (still text body, all formatted as numbered list)

Cook pasta for half of time needed, add sauce, add provola, put in oven blah blah blah

9. Struffoli
```

And the winner is...

[image: Final result]

### Note

The issue presented in the question seems to happen **only** when the "lower-level" list (let me call it that way) has a *similar* number to the "upper-level" list. I mean, if the ingredients were only 2 or 3 and you type `9.` as chapter number, it may occur that Word understands that you are continuing another list.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by using the Heading1 style (or any styles). If you were OK to manually format them, this issue would not exist.

If you don't need to use the Heading styles (eg, if you're not using a TOC) then remove it and add the style manually (by changing font/color and size piecemeal).

(I give full details more for other visitors as the OP shows they can do it) So, if not needing a TOC, create the bullet for the 5 titles, each as a numbered list. Type in the chapter headings. At the end of Chapter1, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and type the blah blah. Repeat for Chapter2.

Now, for chapter 3, repeat as above (press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, type blah blah) and then press return. You'll get number 4. At this point press <kbd>tab</kbd>, and it will indent with number 1. Continue for all the bullets. When finished, press either <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to type underneath, or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to unindent the number.

Alternatively, when you've created your indented numbers, you can drag one of them left / right moving all the indents.

[image]

I now click (with mouse) the end of Chapter 2 and press return to create a new entry and my results are:

[image]